# Eclipse and Google APIs Client Library for Java

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api, m2eclipse, google-api-java-client

I want to use the Client libraries which google provides in order to access their APIs. I've followed several instructions on their website to setup my eclipse and work with the library but I can't.

I've wrote a code similar to Google-tasks-sample and everytime I try to run it, Eclipse freezes and after a few seconds it crashes.
Console output:

```
[2012-01-07 12:30:22 - AdsenseNotify] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

[2012-01-07 12:30:24 - AdsenseNotify] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:745)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:961)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

It also gives a error dialog with "GC limit overhead" and after that, I'm forced to close the workbench.

I'm using eclipse. Already installed the plugins required.
I downloaded the google library and added the jars to my project>build path>external jars  but The error still exists.

Comment: It seems your jars complied versions are not matching. It seems the jar is commons log jar which is not at required compilation for google jar.

Comment: So what should I do? I'm using the default dependency jar files that were provided when I downloaded the libraries.

Comment: I would suggest findout correct version of Jars. You may need to refer the release notes/forums to findout supporting jar versions.

Comment: wait before JUMPING!. What are your compiler settings in Eclipse for this project?   Both of them in fact..it may be as simple as you might have one of the compiler settings not set right

Comment: Hey @FredGrott how should i check my compiler settings in Eclipse?